# Pandas: Create several rows from column that is a list

Tags: pandas

Let's say I have something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,3], 'type':[[1,3],[1,2,3],[1,2]], 'value':[5,1,8]})

key type        value
1   [1, 3]      5
2   [1, 2, 3]   1
3   [1]         8
```

Where one of the columns contains a list of items. 
I would like to create several rows for each row that contains multiple types.

Ontaining this:

```
key type  value
1   1     5
1   3     5
2   1     1
2   2     1
2   3     1
3   1     8
```

I've been playing with apply with axis=1 but I can't find a way to return more than 1 row per row of the DataFrame.
Extracting all different 'types' and then looping-concatenating seems to be ugly.

any ideas? 
Thanks!!!

Comment: Loop concatenate is the way to go. If you are reluctant of doing so because it 'seems to be ugly', the real ugly thing here is to build a dataframe with list in columns in the first place. Avoid building such a column upfront is the right way to go and you problem will disappear nicely.

Comment: I inherited the DataFrame :) I'll try the loop-concat approach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def melt_series(s):
    lengths = s.str.len().values
    flat = [i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.values.tolist())]
    idx = np.repeat(s.index.values, lengths)
    return pd.Series(flat, idx, name=s.name)


melt_series(df.type).to_frame().join(df.drop('type', 1)).reindex_axis(df.columns, 1)
```

[image]

---

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,3],
                   'type':[[1,3],[1,2,3],[1,2]],
                   'value':[5,1,8]})
df
```

[image]