# How to unnest (explode) a column in a pandas DataFrame, into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-explode

I have the following DataFrame where one of the columns is an object (list type cell):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [[1, 2], [1, 2]]})
```

Output:

```
   A       B
0  1  [1, 2]
1  2  [1, 2]
```

My expected output is:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
3  2  1
4  2  2
```

What should I do to achieve this?

---

Related question

[Pandas column of lists, create a row for each list element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263805/pandas-when-cell-contents-are-lists-create-a-row-for-each-element-in-the-list)

Good question and answer but only handle one column with list(In my answer the self-def function will work for multiple columns, also the accepted answer is use the most time consuming `apply` , which is not recommended, check more info [When should I (not) want to use pandas apply() in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code))

Comment: Related, unnesting strings: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48197234/4909087

Comment: Couple of related posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885143/explode-lists-with-different-lengths-in-pandas?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871154/how-to-efficiently-create-a-pivot-table), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558954/pandas-dataframe-explode-column-contents), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743092/exploding-a-pandas-dataframe-column), ...

Answer (score 333, accepted):

I know `object` dtype columns makes the data hard to convert with pandas functions. When I receive data like this, the first thing that came to mind was to "flatten" or unnest the columns.

I am using pandas and Python functions for this type of question. If you are worried about the speed of the above solutions, check out [user3483203's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219045), since it's using numpy and most of the time numpy is faster. I recommend [Cython](https://cython.org/) or [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) if speed matters.

---

**Method 0 [pandas >= 0.25]**
Starting from [pandas 0.25](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/reshaping.html#exploding-a-list-like-column), if you only need to explode *one* column, you can use the [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) function:

```
df.explode('B')

       A  B
    0  1  1
    1  1  2
    0  2  1
    1  2  2
```

Given a dataframe with an empty `list` or a `NaN` in the column. An empty list will not cause an issue, but a `NaN` will need to be filled with a `list`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],'B': [[1, 2], [1, 2], [], np.nan]})
df.B = df.B.fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})  # replace NaN with []
df.explode('B')

   A    B
0  1    1
0  1    2
1  2    1
1  2    2
2  3  NaN
3  4  NaN
```

---

**Method 1**
**`apply + pd.Series`** (easy to understand but in terms of performance not recommended . )

```
df.set_index('A').B.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'B'})
Out[463]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
0  2  1
1  2  2
```

---

**Method 2**
Using `repeat` with `DataFrame` constructor , re-create your dataframe (good at performance, not good at multiple columns )

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':df.A.repeat(df.B.str.len()),'B':np.concatenate(df.B.values)})
df
Out[465]:
   A  B
0  1  1
0  1  2
1  2  1
1  2  2
```

**Method 2.1**
for example besides A we have A.1 .....A.n. If we still use the method(**Method 2**) above it is hard for us to re-create the columns one by one .

Solution : `join` or `merge` with the `index` after 'unnest' the single columns

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'B':np.concatenate(df.B.values)},index=df.index.repeat(df.B.str.len()))
s.join(df.drop('B',1),how='left')
Out[477]:
   B  A
0  1  1
0  2  1
1  1  2
1  2  2
```

If you need the column order exactly the same as before, add `reindex` at the end.

```
s.join(df.drop('B',1),how='left').reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

---

**Method 3**
recreate the `list`

```
pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in df.values for z in y],columns=df.columns)
Out[488]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

If more than two columns, use

```
s=pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in zip(df.index,df.B) for z in y])
s.merge(df,left_on=0,right_index=True)
Out[491]:
   0  1  A       B
0  0  1  1  [1, 2]
1  0  2  1  [1, 2]
2  1  1  2  [1, 2]
3  1  2  2  [1, 2]
```

---

**Method 4**
using `reindex`  or `loc`

```
df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.B.str.len())).assign(B=np.concatenate(df.B.values))
Out[554]:
   A  B
0  1  1
0  1  2
1  2  1
1  2  2

#df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.B.str.len())].assign(B=np.concatenate(df.B.values))
```

---

**Method 5**
when the list only contains unique values:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2],[3,4]]})
from collections import ChainMap
d = dict(ChainMap(*map(dict.fromkeys, df['B'], df['A'])))
pd.DataFrame(list(d.items()),columns=df.columns[::-1])
Out[574]:
   B  A
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  3  2
3  4  2
```

---

**Method 6**
using `numpy` for high performance:

```
newvalues=np.dstack((np.repeat(df.A.values,list(map(len,df.B.values))),np.concatenate(df.B.values)))
pd.DataFrame(data=newvalues[0],columns=df.columns)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

---

**Method 7**
using base function `itertools` `cycle` and `chain`: Pure python solution just for fun

```
from itertools import cycle,chain
l=df.values.tolist()
l1=[list(zip([x[0]], cycle(x[1])) if len([x[0]]) > len(x[1]) else list(zip(cycle([x[0]]), x[1]))) for x in l]
pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(l1)),columns=df.columns)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

---

**Generalizing to multiple columns**

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2],[3,4]],'C':[[1,2],[3,4]]})
df
Out[592]:
   A       B       C
0  1  [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4]
```

Self-def function:

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')


unnesting(df,['B','C'])
Out[609]:
   B  C  A
0  1  1  1
0  2  2  1
1  3  3  2
1  4  4  2
```

---

#### **Column-wise Unnesting**

All above method is talking about the ***vertical*** unnesting and explode , If you do need expend the list ***horizontal***, Check with `pd.DataFrame` constructor

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.B.tolist(),index=df.index).add_prefix('B_'))
Out[33]:
   A       B       C  B_0  B_1
0  1  [1, 2]  [1, 2]    1    2
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4]    3    4
```

**Updated function**

```
def unnesting(df, explode, axis):
    if axis==1:
        idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
        df1 = pd.concat([
            pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
        df1.index = idx

        return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
    else :
        df1 = pd.concat([
                         pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix(x) for x in explode], axis=1)
        return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Test Output

```
unnesting(df, ['B','C'], axis=0)
Out[36]:
   B0  B1  C0  C1  A
0   1   2   1   2  1
1   3   4   3   4  2
```

> Update 2021-02-17 with original explode function

```
def unnesting(df, explode, axis):
    if axis==1:
        df1 = pd.concat([df[x].explode() for x in explode], axis=1)
        return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
    else :
        df1 = pd.concat([
                         pd.DataFrame(df[x].tolist(), index=df.index).add_prefix(x) for x in explode], axis=1)
        return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Comment: As of version 1.3.0 we can explode() multiple columns at once.

Comment: If you have a column of Series objects (and no duplicates in the outer column's index) and want to go straight to long format while preserving inner indexes, you can do `pd.concat(df[x].to_dict())`.

It will stack all values of the inner series while appending their corresponding index values to the (multi)index of the returned object.

Comment: If column wise operation does not work, check if the data type is str. If yes, convert into list.

Answer (score 54):

***Option 1***

If all of the sublists in the other column are the same length, `numpy` can be an efficient option here:

```
vals = np.array(df.B.values.tolist())    
a = np.repeat(df.A, vals.shape[1])

pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((a, vals.ravel())), columns=df.columns)
```

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

---

***Option 2***

If the sublists have different length, you need an additional step:

```
vals = df.B.values.tolist()
rs = [len(r) for r in vals]    
a = np.repeat(df.A, rs)

pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((a, np.concatenate(vals))), columns=df.columns)
```

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

---

***Option 3***

I took a shot at generalizing this to work to flatten `N` columns and tile `M` columns, I'll work later on making it more efficient:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [[1,2], [1,2,3], [1]],
                   'C': [[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2]], 'D': ['A', 'B', 'C']})
```

```
   A          B          C  D
0  1     [1, 2]  [1, 2, 3]  A
1  2  [1, 2, 3]     [1, 2]  B
2  3        [1]     [1, 2]  C
```

```
def unnest(df, tile, explode):
    vals = df[explode].sum(1)
    rs = [len(r) for r in vals]
    a = np.repeat(df[tile].values, rs, axis=0)
    b = np.concatenate(vals.values)
    d = np.column_stack((a, b))
    return pd.DataFrame(d, columns = tile +  ['_'.join(explode)])

unnest(df, ['A', 'D'], ['B', 'C'])
```

```
    A  D B_C
0   1  A   1
1   1  A   2
2   1  A   1
3   1  A   2
4   1  A   3
5   2  B   1
6   2  B   2
7   2  B   3
8   2  B   1
9   2  B   2
10  3  C   1
11  3  C   1
12  3  C   2
```

---

***Functions***

```
def wen1(df):
    return df.set_index('A').B.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0: 'B'})

def wen2(df):
    return pd.DataFrame({'A':df.A.repeat(df.B.str.len()),'B':np.concatenate(df.B.values)})

def wen3(df):
    s = pd.DataFrame({'B': np.concatenate(df.B.values)}, index=df.index.repeat(df.B.str.len()))
    return s.join(df.drop('B', 1), how='left')

def wen4(df):
    return pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in df.values for z in y],columns=df.columns)

def chris1(df):
    vals = np.array(df.B.values.tolist())
    a = np.repeat(df.A, vals.shape[1])
    return pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((a, vals.ravel())), columns=df.columns)

def chris2(df):
    vals = df.B.values.tolist()
    rs = [len(r) for r in vals]
    a = np.repeat(df.A.values, rs)
    return pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((a, np.concatenate(vals))), columns=df.columns)
```

***Timings***

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['wen1', 'wen2', 'wen3', 'wen4', 'chris1', 'chris2'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000],
       dtype=float
)

for f in res.index:
    for c in res.columns:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [[1, 2], [1, 2]]})
        df = pd.concat([df]*c)
        stmt = '{}(df)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import df, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True)
ax.set_xlabel("N")
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)")
```

***Performance***

[image]

Comment: Interesting, would be nice to know the comparison with the new `df.explode` method.

Answer (score 18):

Exploding a list-like column has been [simplified significantly in pandas 0.25](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/reshaping.html#exploding-a-list-like-column) with the addition of the `explode()` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [[1, 2], [1, 2]]})
df.explode('B')
```

Out:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
0  1  2
1  2  1
1  2  2
```

Comment: but this does not work anymore in newer versions of pandas, where the original list is kept in each row column value 
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html

Comment: @FernandoJesusGarciaHipola It works for me in 2.0.1, which version are you on?

Answer (score 12):

One alternative is to apply the [meshgrid recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays) over the rows of the columns to unnest:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def unnest(frame, explode):
    def mesh(values):
        return np.array(np.meshgrid(*values)).T.reshape(-1, len(values))

    data = np.vstack(mesh(row) for row in frame[explode].values)
    return pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=explode)


df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [[1, 2], [1, 2]]})
print(unnest(df, ['A', 'B']))  # base
print()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [[1, 2], [3, 4]], 'C': [[1, 2], [3, 4]]})
print(unnest(df, ['A', 'B', 'C']))  # multiple columns
print()

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1]],
                   'C': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2]], 'D': ['A', 'B', 'C']})

print(unnest(df, ['A', 'B']))  # uneven length lists
print()
print(unnest(df, ['D', 'B']))  # different types
print()
```

**Output**

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  2  1
2  1  1  2
3  1  2  2
4  2  3  3
5  2  4  3
6  2  3  4
7  2  4  4

   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
4  2  3
5  3  1

   D  B
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  1
3  B  2
4  B  3
5  C  1
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Problem Setup

Assume there are multiple columns with different length objects within it

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2],
    'B': [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    'C': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
})

df

   A       B          C
0  1  [1, 2]     [1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]
```

When the lengths are the same, it is easy for us to assume that the varying elements coincide and should be "zipped" together.

```
   A       B          C
0  1  [1, 2]     [1, 2]  # Typical to assume these should be zipped [(1, 1), (2, 2)]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]
```

However, the assumption gets challenged when we see different length objects, should we "zip", if so, how do we handle the excess in one of the objects.  **OR**, maybe we want the product of all of the objects.  This will get big fast, but might be what is wanted.

```
   A       B          C
0  1  [1, 2]     [1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]  # is this [(3, 3), (4, 4), (None, 5)]?
```

**OR**

```
   A       B          C
0  1  [1, 2]     [1, 2]
1  2  [3, 4]  [3, 4, 5]  # is this [(3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5)]
```

---

#### The Function

This function gracefully handles `zip` or `product` based on a parameter and assumes to `zip` according to the length of the longest object with `zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest, product

def xplode(df, explode, zipped=True):
    method = zip_longest if zipped else product

    rest = {*df} - {*explode}

    zipped = zip(zip(*map(df.get, rest)), zip(*map(df.get, explode)))
    tups = [tup + exploded
     for tup, pre in zipped
     for exploded in method(*pre)]

    return pd.DataFrame(tups, columns=[*rest, *explode])[[*df]]
```

---

#### Zipped

```
xplode(df, ['B', 'C'])

   A    B  C
0  1  1.0  1
1  1  2.0  2
2  2  3.0  3
3  2  4.0  4
4  2  NaN  5
```

---

#### Product

```
xplode(df, ['B', 'C'], zipped=False)

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  2
2  1  2  1
3  1  2  2
4  2  3  3
5  2  3  4
6  2  3  5
7  2  4  3
8  2  4  4
9  2  4  5
```

---

#### New Setup

Varying up the example a bit

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2],
    'B': [[1, 2], [3, 4]],
    'C': 'C',
    'D': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],
    'E': [('X', 'Y', 'Z'), ('W',)]
})

df

   A       B  C          D          E
0  1  [1, 2]  C     [1, 2]  (X, Y, Z)
1  2  [3, 4]  C  [3, 4, 5]       (W,)
```

---

#### Zipped

```
xplode(df, ['B', 'D', 'E'])

   A    B  C    D     E
0  1  1.0  C  1.0     X
1  1  2.0  C  2.0     Y
2  1  NaN  C  NaN     Z
3  2  3.0  C  3.0     W
4  2  4.0  C  4.0  None
5  2  NaN  C  5.0  None
```

---

#### Product

```
xplode(df, ['B', 'D', 'E'], zipped=False)

    A  B  C  D  E
0   1  1  C  1  X
1   1  1  C  1  Y
2   1  1  C  1  Z
3   1  1  C  2  X
4   1  1  C  2  Y
5   1  1  C  2  Z
6   1  2  C  1  X
7   1  2  C  1  Y
8   1  2  C  1  Z
9   1  2  C  2  X
10  1  2  C  2  Y
11  1  2  C  2  Z
12  2  3  C  3  W
13  2  3  C  4  W
14  2  3  C  5  W
15  2  4  C  3  W
16  2  4  C  4  W
17  2  4  C  5  W
```

Answer (score 3):

My 5 cents:

```
df[['B', 'B2']] = pd.DataFrame(df['B'].values.tolist())

df[['A', 'B']].append(df[['A', 'B2']].rename(columns={'B2': 'B'}),
                      ignore_index=True)
```

and another 5

```
df[['B1', 'B2']] = pd.DataFrame([*df['B']]) # if values.tolist() is too boring

(pd.wide_to_long(df.drop('B', 1), 'B', 'A', '')
 .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
 .reset_index())
```

both resulting in the same

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  1  2
3  2  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Because normally sublist length are different and join/merge is far more computational expensive. I retested the method for different length sublist and more normal columns.

MultiIndex should be also a easier way to write and has near the same performances as numpy way.

Surprisingly, in my implementation comprehension way has the best performance.

```
def stack(df):
    return df.set_index(['A', 'C']).B.apply(pd.Series).stack()


def comprehension(df):
    return pd.DataFrame([x + [z] for x, y in zip(df[['A', 'C']].values.tolist(), df.B) for z in y])


def multiindex(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(df.B.values), index=df.set_index(['A', 'C']).index.repeat(df.B.str.len()))


def array(df):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.column_stack((
            np.repeat(df[['A', 'C']].values, df.B.str.len(), axis=0),
            np.concatenate(df.B.values)
        ))
    )


import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[
        'stack',
        'comprehension',
        'multiindex',
        'array',
    ],
    columns=[1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 20000, 50000],
    dtype=float
)

for f in res.index:
    for c in res.columns:
        df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abc'), 'C': list('def'), 'B': [['g', 'h', 'i'], ['j', 'k'], ['l']]})
        df = pd.concat([df] * c)
        stmt = '{}(df)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import df, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=20)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True)
ax.set_xlabel("N")
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)")
```

### Performance

[Relative time of each method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SFWo.png)

Answer (score 2):

I generalized the problem a bit to be applicable to more columns.

**Summary of what my solution does:**

```
In[74]: df
Out[74]: 
    A   B             C             columnD
0  A1  B1  [C1.1, C1.2]                D1
1  A2  B2  [C2.1, C2.2]  [D2.1, D2.2, D2.3]
2  A3  B3            C3        [D3.1, D3.2]

In[75]: dfListExplode(df,['C','columnD'])
Out[75]: 
    A   B     C columnD
0  A1  B1  C1.1    D1
1  A1  B1  C1.2    D1
2  A2  B2  C2.1    D2.1
3  A2  B2  C2.1    D2.2
4  A2  B2  C2.1    D2.3
5  A2  B2  C2.2    D2.1
6  A2  B2  C2.2    D2.2
7  A2  B2  C2.2    D2.3
8  A3  B3    C3    D3.1
9  A3  B3    C3    D3.2
```

Complete example:

**The actual explosion is performed in 3 lines.** The rest is cosmetics (multi column explosion, handling of strings instead of lists in the explosion column, ...).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame( {'A': ['A1','A2','A3'],
                  'B': ['B1','B2','B3'],
                  'C': [ ['C1.1','C1.2'],['C2.1','C2.2'],'C3'],
                  'columnD': [ 'D1',['D2.1','D2.2', 'D2.3'],['D3.1','D3.2']],
                  })
print('df',df, sep='\n')

def dfListExplode(df, explodeKeys):
    if not isinstance(explodeKeys, list):
        explodeKeys=[explodeKeys]
    # recursive handling of explodeKeys
    if len(explodeKeys)==0:
        return df
    elif len(explodeKeys)==1:
        explodeKey=explodeKeys[0]
    else:
        return dfListExplode( dfListExplode(df, explodeKeys[:1]), explodeKeys[1:])
    # perform explosion/unnesting for key: explodeKey
    dfPrep=df[explodeKey].apply(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,list) else [x]) #casts all elements to a list
    dfIndExpl=pd.DataFrame([[x] + [z] for x, y in zip(dfPrep.index,dfPrep.values) for z in y ], columns=['explodedIndex',explodeKey])
    dfMerged=dfIndExpl.merge(df.drop(explodeKey, axis=1), left_on='explodedIndex', right_index=True)
    dfReind=dfMerged.reindex(columns=list(df))
    return dfReind

dfExpl=dfListExplode(df,['C','columnD'])
print('dfExpl',dfExpl, sep='\n')
```

Credits to [WeNYoBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53218939/7128154)

Answer (score 1):

Something pretty not recommended (at least work in this case):

```
df=pd.concat([df]*2).sort_index()
it=iter(df['B'].tolist()[0]+df['B'].tolist()[0])
df['B']=df['B'].apply(lambda x:next(it))
```

`concat` + `sort_index` + `iter` + `apply` + `next`.

Now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
0  1  2
1  2  1
1  2  2
```

If care about index:

```
df=df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  1
3  2  2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2],[1,2]]})

pd.concat([df['A'], pd.DataFrame(df['B'].values.tolist())], axis = 1)\
  .melt(id_vars = 'A', value_name = 'B')\
  .dropna()\
  .drop('variable', axis = 1)

    A   B
0   1   1
1   2   1
2   1   2
3   2   2
```

Any opinions on this method I thought of? or is doing both concat and melt considered too "expensive"?

Answer (score 1):

I have another good way to solves this when you have more than one column to explode.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2],[1,2]], 'C':[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]})

print(df)
   A       B          C
0  1  [1, 2]  [1, 2, 3]
1  2  [1, 2]  [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to explode the columns B and C. First I explode B, second C. Than I drop B and C from the original df. After that I will do an index join on the 3 dfs.

```
explode_b = df.explode('B')['B']
explode_c = df.explode('C')['C']
df = df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)
df = df.join([explode_b, explode_c])
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple function for horizontal explode, based on @BEN_YO's answer.

```
import typing
import pandas as pd

def horizontal_explode(df: pd.DataFrame, col_name: str, new_columns: typing.Union[list, None]=None) -> pd.DataFrame:
    t = pd.DataFrame(df[col_name].tolist(), columns=new_columns, index=df.index)
    return pd.concat([df, t], axis=1)
```

Running example:

```
items = [
    ["1", ["a", "b", "c"]],
    ["2", ["d", "e", "f"]]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns = ["col1", "col2"])
print(df)

t = horizontal_explode(df=df, col_name="col2")
del t["col2"]
print(t)

t = horizontal_explode(df=df, col_name="col2", new_columns=["new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3"])
del t["col2"]
print(t)
```

This the relevant output:

```
  col1       col2
0    1  [a, b, c]
1    2  [d, e, f]

  col1  0  1  2
0    1  a  b  c
1    2  d  e  f

  col1 new_col1 new_col2 new_col3
0    1        a        b        c
1    2        d        e        f
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 demo = {'set1':{'t1':[1,2,3],'t2':[4,5,6],'t3':[7,8,9]}, 'set2':{'t1':[1,2,3],'t2':[4,5,6],'t3':[7,8,9]}, 'set3': {'t1':[1,2,3],'t2':[4,5,6],'t3':[7,8,9]}}
 df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(demo, orient='index') 

 print(df.head())
 my_list=[]
 df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['set','t1','t2','t3'])

 for key,item in df.iterrows():
    t1=item.t1
    t2=item.t2
    t3=item.t3
    mat1=np.matrix([t1,t2,t3])
    row1=[key,mat1[0,0],mat1[0,1],mat1[0,2]]
    df2.loc[len(df2)]=row1
    row2=[key,mat1[1,0],mat1[1,1],mat1[1,2]]
    df2.loc[len(df2)]=row2
    row3=[key,mat1[2,0],mat1[2,1],mat1[2,2]]
    df2.loc[len(df2)]=row3

print(df2) 

set t1 t2 t3
0  set1  1  2  3
1  set1  4  5  6
2  set1  7  8  9
3  set2  1  2  3
4  set2  4  5  6
5  set2  7  8  9
6  set3  1  2  3
7  set3  4  5  6
8  set3  7  8  9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2],'B':[[1,2],[1,2]]})

out = pd.concat([df.loc[:,'A'],(df.B.apply(pd.Series))], axis=1, sort=False)

out = out.set_index('A').stack().droplevel(level=1).reset_index().rename(columns={0:"B"})

       A    B
   0    1   1
   1    1   2
   2    2   1
   3    2   2
```

- you can implement this as one liner, if you don't wish to create intermediate object

Answer (score 0):

```
# Here's the answer to the related question in:
# https://stackoverflow.com/q/56708671/11426125

# initial dataframe
df12=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2007-12-03','2008-09-07'],'names':
[['Peter','Alex'],['Donald','Stan']]})

# convert dataframe to array for indexing list values (names)
a = np.array(df12.values)  

# create a new, dataframe with dimensions for unnested
b = np.ndarray(shape = (4,2))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns = ["Date", "names"], dtype = str)

# implement loops to assign date/name values as required
i = range(len(a[0]))
j = range(len(a[0]))
for x in i:
    for y in j:
        df2.iat[2*x+y, 0] = a[x][0]
        df2.iat[2*x+y, 1] = a[x][1][y]

# set Date column as Index
df2.Date=pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df2.index=df2.Date
df2.drop('Date',axis=1,inplace =True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case with more than one column to explode, and with variables lengths for the arrays that needs to be unnested.

I ended up applying the new pandas 0.25 `explode` function two times, then removing generated duplicates and it does the job !

```py
df = df.explode('A')
df = df.explode('B')
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```